# spark Athena connector

Tags: pyspark, amazon-athena

I need to use Athena in spark but spark uses preparedStatement when using JDBC drivers and it gives me an exception
"com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.NotImplementedException: Method Connection.prepareStatement is not yet implemented"

Can you please let me know how can I connect Athena in spark

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know how you'd connect to Athena from Spark, but you don't need to - you can very easily query the data that Athena contains (or, more correctly, "registers") from Spark.

There are two parts to Athena

1. Hive Metastore (now called the Glue Data Catalog) which contains mappings between database and table names and all underlying files
2. Presto query engine which translates your SQL into data operations against those files

When you start an EMR cluster (v5.8.0 and later) you can instruct it to connect to your Glue Data Catalog. This is a checkbox in the 'create cluster' dialog. When you check this option your Spark `SqlContext` will connect to the Glue Data Catalog, and you'll be able to see the tables in Athena.

You can then query these tables as normal.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html for more.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of "You can then query these tables as normal."  My queries are coming back all nulls

Comment: If you run (from Athena) `describe table mytable` you should be able to see the location of the data. Check that it's correct. You don't want the table data saved on the EMR cluster, but instead need it on s3.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this JDBC driver: [SimbaAthenaJDBC](https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.2/docs/Simba+Athena+JDBC+Driver+Install+and+Configuration+Guide.pdf)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.syncron.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>simba-athena-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

to use:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("My Spark Example")
    .getOrCreate();

Class.forName("com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver");

Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
connectionProperties.put("User", "AWSAccessKey");
connectionProperties.put("Password", "AWSSecretAccessKey");
connectionProperties.put("S3OutputLocation", "s3://my-bucket/tmp/");
connectionProperties.put("AwsCredentialsProviderClass", 
    "com.simba.athena.amazonaws.auth.PropertiesFileCredentialsProvider");
connectionProperties.put("AwsCredentialsProviderArguments", "/my-folder/.athenaCredentials");
connectionProperties.put("driver", "com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver");

List<String> predicateList =
    Stream
        .of("id = 'foo' and date >= DATE'2018-01-01' and date < DATE'2019-01-01'")
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
String[] predicates = new String[predicateList.size()];
predicates = predicateList.toArray(predicates);

Dataset<Row> data =
    spark.read()
        .jdbc("jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-east-1;",
            "my_env.my_table", predicates, connectionProperties);
```

You can also use this driver in a Flink application:

```
TypeInformation[] fieldTypes = new TypeInformation[] {
    BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
    BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO
};

RowTypeInfo rowTypeInfo = new RowTypeInfo(fieldTypes);

JDBCInputFormat jdbcInputFormat = JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
    .setDrivername("com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver")
    .setDBUrl("jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=us-east-1;UID=my_access_key;PWD=my_secret_key;S3OutputLocation=s3://my-bucket/tmp/;")
    .setQuery("select id, val_col from my_env.my_table WHERE id = 'foo' and date >= DATE'2018-01-01' and date < DATE'2019-01-01'")
    .setRowTypeInfo(rowTypeInfo)
    .finish();

DataSet<Row> dbData = env.createInput(jdbcInputFormat, rowTypeInfo);
```

Comment: In the first example how can i use a database name instead of specifying table name in jdbc url.

Comment: @rakeeee "my_env.my_table" = "my_database.my_table".  If you want to connect to an additional table, make an additional JDBC connection.

Comment: @Wil Why do we need to put `User` and `Password` in the properties?..as I suppose that is already available in `/my-folder/.athenaCredentials`? Also, what should be the format of the `.athenaCredentials` file? I tried the format as suggested here https://www.simba.com/products/Athena/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/ath/examples/jdkexamples.htm. ... but I am still getting this error... ```Caused by: com.simba.athena.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. The security token included in the request is invalid```

Comment: @Raj there are 2 different examples above, one for Flink and one for Spark.  At the time of writing, that was how I got the driver to work with Flink, but I would imagine that the newer versions of Flink would support the credentials file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly connect Spark to Athena.  Athena is simply an implementation of [Prestodb](https://prestodb.io/) targeting s3.  Unlike Presto, Athena cannot target data on HDFS.

However, if you want to use Spark to query data in s3, then you are in luck with [HUE](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/11/07/amazon-elastic-mapreduce-now-supports-hue/), which will let you query data in s3 from [Spark on Elastic Map Reduce (EMR)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-apache-spark-on-amazon-emr/).

**See Also:**
[Developer Guide for Hadoop User Experience (HUE) on EMR.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hue.html)

Comment: It's actually possible to connect spark to Athena using the Athena jdbc driver, as presented before.

Answer (score 1):

The response of @Kirk Broadhurst is correct if you want to use the **data** of Athena.
If you want to use the Athena engine, then, there is a lib on [github](https://github.com/tmheo/spark-athena) that overcomes the `preparedStatement` problem.

Note that I didn't succeed to use the lib, due to my lack of experience with Maven etc

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use B2W's Spark Athena Driver.

https://github.com/B2W-BIT/athena-spark-driver