# Is there a way to query AWS Athena with PySpark from Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I am able to query SQL database without any problem except for Athena AWS. There seems to not be any connection string that works for it. I tried to follow [spark Athena connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672749/spark-athena-connector) but it requires AWS Glue. I want to be able to query Athena AWS from Jupyter Notebook with a JDBC connector that I downloaded from Amazon AWS.

Here is an example of PyAthena that works well with Pandas but not with PySpark.  https://pypi.org/project/PyAthena/

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't have an answer, but did you manage to solve your problem? I am trying to do the same couldn't solve it though.

Comment: I gave up on this and just query Aws Athena directly from AWS Console instead.