# Accessing Athena View from EMR pyspark, recreating external table or glue catalog, most effecient way

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have read other question and I am confused about the option. I want to read a `Athena view` in EMR spark and from searching on google/stackoverflow, I realized that these view are somehow stored in S3, so I first tried to find the external location of the view through

```
Describe mydb.Myview
```

It provides schema but doesnt provide the external location. From which I assumed that I cannot read it as Dataframe from `S3`

**What i have considered so far for reading athena view in Spark**

I have considered following options

1. Make a new table out of this athena VIEW using WITH statment with external format as `PARQUET`

   `CREATE TABLE Temporary_tbl_from_view WITH ( format = 'PARQUET', external_location = 's3://my-bucket/views_to_parquet/',  )  AS ( SELECT * FROM "mydb"."myview"; );`

2. Another option is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48432897/3680831),which suggests

> When you start an EMR cluster (v5.8.0 and later) you can instruct it
> to connect to your Glue Data Catalog. This is a checkbox in the
> 'create cluster' dialog. When you check this option your Spark
> SqlContext will connect to the Glue Data Catalog, and you'll be able
> to see the tables in Athena.

but I am not sure how can I query this `view` (not table) in pyspark if athena table/views are available  through `Glue catalogue` in spark context, will the simple statement like this work?

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from mydbmyview")
```

**Question**, What is the more effecient way to read this view in spark, does recreating a table using WITH statement (external location) means that I am storing this thing in `Glue catalog` or `S3` twice? If yes, How can I read it directly through S3 or glue catalog?

Comment: AB were you able to solve this?

Comment: @AlfredoLozano I have posted my solution as answer, hope it helps. Sorry for delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to share the solution I followed with others, I created my cluster with the following option enabled

```
Use AWS Glue Data Catalog for table metadata
```

Afterwards, I saw the `database` name from AWS GLUE and Was able to see the desired view in `tablename` as below

```
spark.sql("use my_db_name")
spark.sql("show tables").show(truncate=False)
+------------+---------------------------+-----------+
|database    |tableName                  |isTemporary|
+------------+---------------------------+-----------+
|  my_db_name|tabel1                     |false      |
|  my_db_name|desired_table              |false      |
|  my_db_name|tabel3                     |false      |
+------------+---------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: you can see the view through "show tables" comment. However, EMR pyspark cannot read from athena view, reading from athena table is ok

Comment: are you saying we can simply query like we query regular tables(not view) if we enable options you've mentioned?